# Search two websites simultaneously and display results on one page side by side

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am modifying a code to write a search form to search Google and MyWebsite at the same time, and then display results from Google and results from MyWebsite on one page side by side. (I have no need of comparing the results)

This is the code I have:

```
// to be placed in the head of my page
<script type="text/javascript">
  function dosearch() {
    var sf=document.searchform;
    var submitto = sf.sengines.options[sf.sengines.selectedIndex].value + escape(sf.searchterms.value);
    window.location.href = submitto;
    return false;
  }
</script>

// to be placed where I want the search box to appear
<form name="searchform" onSubmit="return dosearch();">
  Search:
  <select name="sengines">
    <option value="http://www.google.com/search?q=" selected>Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.mywebsite.com/search?q=">MyWebsite</option>
  </select>
  For:
  <input type="text" name="searchterms">
  <input type="submit" name="SearchSubmit" value="Search">
</form>
```

The above code allows me to use either Google or MyWebsite to perform my search one after the other (not at the same time) and the results are displayed on different page other than where the search form is.

**What I want to do exactly is**.

1. Instead of being limited to selecting one search engine at a time,
   I want check boxes to select the two search engines at the same
   time.
2. Enter one search term to fetch results from both search
   engines at the same time and displayed on one same page side by side using
   `iframe` or something better.

Here is a [link to an image of what I am looking for](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2Fkm-lsU6xHVDdzSnFpUi1qVFk/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Please do not type sentences in all uppercase characters because it sounds like you are yelling at somebody. Instead use the formatting options (like bold) to add emphasis to the statement. Thanks notes are considered as fluff and there is no need to add them in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: After looking deeper, you can't* do this with most search engines because they block iframes.
<sub>*Technically there are workarounds but they're out of the scope of this question.
(The easiest way would be to create a php page that echos the page. Ask google)</sub>

---

Assuming that both searches use URL variables to get the query, you could do something like:

```
var search1 = document.createElement("iframe");
search1.src = "http://www.asearch.com?q=" + query;
var search2 = document.createElement("iframe");
search2.src = "http://www.anothersearch.com?query=" + query;

document.body.appendChild(search1);
document.body.appendChild(search2);
```

You'll have to figure out how each search engine works and change the `?q=` respectively.

Final result:

```js
// JavaScript
function dosearch() {
  var query = document.getElementById("query").value
  
  if (document.getElementById("search1").checked) {
    var search1 = document.getElementById("res1");
    search1.src = "http://www.asearch.com?q=" + query;
  }
  if (document.getElementById("search2").checked) {
    var search2 = document.getElementById("res2");
    search2.src = "http://www.anothersearch.com?q=" + query;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
Search: 
A Search <input type="checkbox" id="search1" checked> 
Another Search <input type="checkbox" id="search2"><br>
For: <input type="text" id="query"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="dosearch();"><br>
<iframe id="res1"><iframe id="res2">
```

Comment: Thanks @ben  for the response. But I couldn't figure how to relate your code with a search form that has check box, please can u modify my code with yours so i can check how urs work as a search box?

Comment: Basically this replaces your `dosearch();` function. Edit coming momentarily.

Comment: @ElizabethKof there you go.

Comment: thank you very much for the effort. But your fuction creates a new iframe anytime a search is performed. It ends up with serveral iframes on a single page. I had wanted two iframes only on a page, each to contain search results from a search engine

Comment: Then have the iframes there from the start and just update the src attribute when a query is performed.

Comment: yes that seems to be the idea. But I am new to coding, I don't how to implement what you have said with code. Please, assist in this repect too thanks

Comment: Not to be rude, by me giving you code to copy paste into your project isn't going to help you learn anything. Find a tutorial, learn the basics of how JavaScript works then try a project like this.

Comment: Or, hire someone to write your JavaScript for you.

Comment: I am sorry you feel this way. But if you can, do assist me

Comment: no pls, this edit created only one iframe instead of two. This site http://bvsg.org/ has what I am looking for. You may examine their source code and give me clue, how I can go about geting something like that. I would appreciate it even if it is just a clue you give (like explaining to me the way they coded their site) I am also examining the source code but I am slow at understanding it